# raw folder in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to play sound effects in a application. Everywhere I look, I am being told to add a *raw* folder in the res directory(working in eclipse).

First, I add the raw folder under res. Then I put my .wav files inside. When I try to use R.raw.filename in my code, I get an error "raw cannot be resolved". So I clean and rebuild the project. Suddenly, everywhere that I used R.id or R.anything is underlined as an error. When I looked up the error, it turns out that it had something to do with Android.R. Nothing I did could fix it. So I removed the raw folder and rebuilt the project. All of a sudden, everything is fine.

I've repeated this process about 4 times and I have no idea why it's such a pain to add the raw folder. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do any of your .wav files contains invalid characters in their name? Check if maybe the following messages are shown somewhere in your build:

> Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.

and

> Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Only lowercase characters, digits, underscore and period are valid for the names plus extensions.

Comment: Capital letters. Wow. I didn't catch the bit about lower case letters. Why even have a rule like that? Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `assets` folder and ...

```
InputStream sound = getAssets().open("filename.mp3");
```

... or `raw` folder and ...

```
InputStream sound = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);
```

Just make sure that the file called `filename` exists in the directory called `raw`.

If all uses of `R.*` are underlined, delete the import `android.R` in the upper part of your class as Maxim mentioned.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get it as an id. I'm not actually playing the sound yet.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your activity added import android.R, after that all references with R goes to android framework (android.jar) which doesn't know anything about your raw files. Just check imports and if you see android.R, delete it and add com.my_app_namespace.R Should work after that

Comment: Didn't work. If there are music files in my raw folder, even my own R does not resolve.

Comment: @Gregory-Turtle ApiDemos, samples how to use android sdk that you can download with SDK. com.example.android.apis.media AudioFxDemo.java (mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_cbr);) And it works, look at it and compare, because you are doing something wrong. test_cbr.mp3 file in the raw folder

Comment: Create separate app and try just raw music load. If it works then mess happened in some other place.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this counts as a solution, but when I used .ogg files instead of .wav files, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: No, it's not. Like @Joe said, do you have hyphens "-" in your file name? This answer should help other people with the same kind of problem to resolve it. To have only option of using .ogg files is not a solution.

Comment: No. My file names only had letters.